# Hebrew in url key

Tags: url-rewrite

I have a store in Hebrew.

I want that the url key of cms pages, categories and products will be in hebrew.
I'm able only to insert english characters.

What can I do?

There is any free extension for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article documents how to support unicode characters in URLs (which would include Hebrew):

http://rakan.me/2012/07/19/support-unicode-in-magento-product-url-key/

Link to the github containing all of the files: https://github.com/rakanalh/Magento-unicode-URL

There's also a paid extension here: http://magendev.com/url-key-master.html